# List the annual sales by companies for all years

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I try on my code but it does not work. I use Northwind database

```
select Year(Orders.OrderDate) as year,
       sum(UnitPrice*Quantity*(1-Discount)) as Revenue
from "Order Details"
inner join Orders on (Orders.OrderID = "Order Details".OrderID)
group by year(Orders.OrderDate);
```

Comment: yes i am. is any other way in SQL Server that I can extract Year information?

Comment: By company? You aren't grouping by company. And you say it doesn't work but you didn't describe how. That looks like a valid query.

Comment: I think in northwind it is only company so I group by year instead

Comment: The problem is year() does not work in query

Comment: Customer rather than company then? I don't remember Northwind very well.

Comment: SQL Server has a year function.

Comment: You can use `datepart(year, ...)` but it's exactly the same as `year()`.

Comment: `it does not work` what is not working ? `List the annual sales by companies` You need to join to another table with `company` attribute